# FancyBox3 YouTube Embed Code Not Displaying

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-3

The FancyBox3 documentation says the following html code works to embed videos.

```
<a data-fancybox href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DEdR5lqnDE">YouTube video</a>
```

It opens the box but shows a chrome error page that says "it may have been moved or deleted". Fancybox3 is working because other iframes load properly. I can even copy the YouTube embed link (not the video url) and use it as shown below and it works. However, I cannot add options such as `&autoplay=1` to the embed url or it breaks it.

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DEdR5lqnDE" href="javascript:;">Youtube Video</a>
```

I am working on the website locally. Is this just an issue with the fancybox embed locally and it should work when run on the web?

Comment: Bear in mind the that the youtube protocol is https that might not work locally in Chrome, otherwise works fine online http://jsfiddle.net/7khajL1g/

Comment: It is not recommended to develop locally. Videos, ajax, iframes can break (depends on browser, too).

Comment: Developing locally was indeed the problem, everything worked once I was able to push it online. Thanks!